# calculating cumulative average growth rate in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to compare the performance of 2 investments by calculating back the cumulative average growth rate.

I have found this formula which works perfectly in excel but I cannot get it to work in php...it simply returns '0' every time:

```
CAGR = (Xn/X0)^(1/t) - 1

where: 
Xn = current market value of portfolio 
X0 = initial portfolio's value 
t = number of years
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `pow` for an exponential expression [Manual: pow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Exponential expression function [pow()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)

```
CAGR = pow(($Xn/$X0),(1/$t)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
$Xn = 123; // current market value of portfolio
$X0 = 50;  // initial portfolio's value
$t = 5;    // number of years
$CAGR = pow( ($Xn / $X0), (1 / $t) ) - 1 ;

print($CAGR);
```